# Does VPNv4 address family requires MPLS?

Tags: l3vpn

i am a bit confused about the concept.
let say i have P2P connection from R1 to R2 with BGP peering.
and lets say i am configuring 2 vrf's on R1:

- VRF1 - RD 1:1 with route-target export 1:1 and route-target import 1:1
- VRF2 - RD 1:2 with route-target export 1:2 and route-target import 1:2

of course when R2 gets the traffic he knows what routes to import to what tables since those statements are carried inside the bgp payload.
now the question is whether its possible to implement such design without "mpls ip" command on the egressing interface ?

truly i couldn't find any good related info for my question.

tnx

Answer (score 2):

It requires MPLS tunneling for transport towards the next-hop PE router. Without MPLS your VPNv4 route will not have a tunnel resolution in the VRF table (hence, the route won't be installed).

MPLS tunneling is used in L3VPNs so that the P routers in the provider core network (MPLS core) won't have to know about the customer VRF routes (possibly many thousands of routes in each VRF) - they only need to know how to reach the PE routers. Following such design, P routers can be relatively lightweight in terms of capacity and processing power.

From pure control plane POV, BGP peering with VPNv4 address-family is sufficient to get the route into the local BGP table (but it won't necessarily have a way to reach the next-hop PE router).

EDIT:
You could theoretically use other types of tunnels to interconnect two(or more) remote VRFs, but without MPLS the tunneling is not scalable.